# Why do i always see some small pixels in the atmosphere when my eyes are open or closed?

Tags: everyday-life

Some small particles falling from the atmosphere are always visible. I wonder why!

Comment: Your question requires more explanation. Maybe more precise description of the effect you see.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) I think it would be helpful if you edited your post to include a bit more of detail - as it is now, it's hard to understand what exactly the phenomenom is and what exactly your interpretation attempt is. I am also unsure whether it might not be more of a biology question - the human eye does after all have some peculiarities of its own.

Comment: What the asker means, is that when you look in the blue sky for some time, you see small circles in the sky and they appear to be falling towards the earth as you move your eyeball downwards! Great question!

Comment: Are you sure they are pixels? Or actual particles?

Comment: If you see them with closed eyes it is not a physics question.

Answer (score 1):

We really need more details about those "stars" you are seeing. Without further description it is impossible to know what you see.

However, another possibility is that you're seeing [floaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater). These would be somewhat larger than "small pixels", and they are quite common. They can be light or dark coloured, and they have a tendency to sink down to the bottom of your vision. In some people they are a permanent feature of the eye, in others they come and go.

The light coloured ones are not normally a problem and are often caused by shrinkage of the gel inside the eye. The dark ones are small clumps of blood cells. While they can be innocuous, it's also possible they are caused by [retinal detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retinal_detachment). In that case they are usually accompanied by other symptoms and it is important that you see an eye doctor.

Comment: Also may be [Scheerer's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon).

Answer (score 0):

"Small pixels" seen whether your eyes are open or closed may be due to visual snow,not a real effect in the atmosphere. (Which in thus case, this question is not a physics one) This rare condition is not very well understood (as of the time of writing) but it may be due to brain hypermetabolism.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_snow